# Use ConfigService in static class

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a static utility class that does some functions.

I am trying to use ConfigService inside a static class. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in static.

I have tried the following way but the static class is loaded first before the config module gets initialized. So the config value is returned as undefined always. How to load the config module in a way to be used in static classes too.

```
//Utils.ts
import AppConfig from './../modules/app/app.config';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export abstract class Essentials {
  private static encryptSalt: number = AppConfig.get('bcryptSalt');

  public static encryptString(input: string): Promise<string> {
    console.log('Essentials.encryptSalt', Essentials.encryptSalt);
    return bcrypt.hash(input, Essentials.encryptSalt);
  }
}
```

This is my AppConfig file. I am just instantiating the ConfigService to be used in the Utils. But it gives undefined for the field `bcryptSalt`

```
//AppConfig.ts
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

export default new ConfigService();
```

This is the config.ts file

```
//config.ts
export default () => ({
    bcryptSalt: parseInt(process.env.ENCRYPTION_SALT_BCRYPT, 10)
});
```

This is how I import it in the App module.

```
//app.module.ts
...
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: [
        `${appDir}/config/env/.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
      ],
      cache: true,
      load: [config],
    })]
})
...
```

Comment: Why does the class have to be static? Generally what you're looking to do here isn't really possible

Comment: I thought having the utilities as static is a good way. Is there any other alternative I can try? I mean like making the Utils as Singleton might help me in injecting the config Object. Can you suggest me a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Like you said, you could make the utilities a singleton injectable that can be used elsewhere, which is what I would do. If you really want it to be static you could use `dotenv` and `process.env` directly, cutting out the `ConfigService` all together

Comment: I already have it as a singleton and when I switched to static I was using process.env directly which was giving me results. But thought there could be some other neat way of doing this. Thank you @JayMcDoniel